# Rails App on AWS Elasticbeanstalk mail send fails with ESMTP No Relay Access Allowed From IP

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, actionmailer, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a rails app that I have deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The app uses devise to handle user authentication, and its set to be able to invite users.
My issue is that when I try to invite a user, I get the following error:

```
Net::SMTPFatalError (554 secureserver.net ESMTP No Relay Access Allowed From <my_eb_assigned_ip>
```

(I am hosting the domain on GoDaddy).

In development, the mailer functionality works fine; my smtp settings are set to (common to all environments):

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtpout.secureserver.net",
    :port => 80,
    :domain => "www.my_domain.com",
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => "do-not-reply@my_domain.com",
    :password => my_pass,
}
```

And in my production.rb config file:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'aws_sb.elasticbeanstalk.com' }
```

Is there another setting I have to enable in Elasticbeanstalk to allow relay access? Or am I missing a production specific setting from my rails configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it was the port value that I was setting....when I switched the port to 25, it works in production. However, for development, port 25 wasn't working; it would only work in dev when the port was 80.

So I ended up moving the entire smtp mailer settings into the environment specific settings (from the config/environment.rb file), and setting the production port to 25, and the development port to 80, and that appeared to make both environments work.

Edit: After another push, I was seeing the same issue, and none of the ports I tried were resolving the issue. So I ended up switching all my mail functionality to be sent through Amazon SES, and that appears to be functioning great so far.